# Scala Concatenate ListBuffer Contents of Class Elements

Tags: scala, concatenation, listbuffer

I am trying to combine the elements of two `ListBuffers` into one single `ListBuffer`. For standard `ListBuffers` I know you can use `++` to accomplish this, however the the `ListBuffer` contains a class as its element.

For example:

```
class ExampleBuffer {
  var exBuff = new ListBuffer[Example]
}

class Example (
  var name: String = null, 
  var age: Option[Int] = None, 
  var yob: Option[Int] = None, 
  var gender: Option[String] = None
)

val e1 = new Example
val e2 = new Example

e1.name = "Jack"
e1.age = Some(25)
e2.yob = Some(1990)
e2.gender = Some("m")

val b1 = ListBuffer(e1)
val b2 = ListBuffer(e2)
val b3 = b1 ++ b2
```

So:

```
b1 = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Example] = ListBuffer(Example@4a60ee36)
b2 = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Example] = ListBuffer(Example@4d33940d)
b3 = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Example] = ListBuffer(Example@4a60ee36, Example@4d33940d)
```

I would like to combine the two to contain all four elements and then pull from this buffer later. The issue is that when I try to concatenate the `ListBuffers`, I am left with `ListBuffer(Example@4a60ee36, Example@4d33940d)`, rather than combining the actual elements of class `Example1` and `Example2`.

Is there a way that I can extract the elements from each `ListBuffer` to add each element to a new `ListBuffer`? Pulling each element individually though `b1(0).name`, etc into a new `ListBuffer` will not be a great method since the real issue I am working with is much larger than the example above.

Comment: The resulting `ListBuffer` contains all your `Example` objects. Add a `toString` method like `override def toString = s"Example($name $age $yob $gender)"` to your `Example` class to see the values of your `Example` objects.

Comment: " combining the actual elements of class Example1 and Example2." What do you mean by this? Your combined b3 contains e1 and e2 - if that's not what you want, can you explain what result you need?

Comment: Thank you for the feed back.

The issue is that I need to be able to pull the values for all four elements directly from the listbuffer.

so b3(0).name will work but b3(0).gender will not with the current orientation.

please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

thank you

Comment: `e1.gender = None` and `b3(0).gender = None`, what do you mean with "_`b3(0).gender` will not work_"?